# Bash Programming - Creating a Custom Terminal Command - Mac

Tags: macos, bash, vi

I tried making a custom command for my terminal. I'm running Mac OS X Version 10.6.6.

Here are the steps I took:

1. Opened the terminal
2. Typed "ls -a" and saw a ".bash_profile" file
3. Typed "vi .bash_profile" and saw that the file was empty
4. Added the following to the top of the file: "test() { echo hi }"
5. Saved the vi session by typing ":wq"

Then, I was back to the terminal, and typed "test", however nothing outputted (namely, I didn't see "hi").

So, what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: or you can just restart the terminal once done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try to force re-evaluation of file by typing `source .bash_profile`

Comment: wow, cool! that worked. what went wrong? and what is "source"

Comment: @reising The `source` command basically parses a file. You probably want to put your function in `.bash_rc`, it will then get auto sourced every time you open the terminal.

Comment: Your profile file only automatically gets loaded when you open a new shell. When you change it you have to either open a new terminal tab or force it to evaluate with `source`.

Comment: @reising1: I suggest not to name your function (AKA custom command) 'test' because of name conflict with a command named 'test'.

Comment: You just needed to restart terminal

Comment: '.bash_rc' didn't get loaded when I open a new terminal. What worked for me is '.bash_profile'. I create/edit it and call 'source .bash_profile'. This works for me. (OSX 10.8.1)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty late, but for future people who google this question, here's what you need to do:

When you edit the bash.profile file, you need to use the `alias` command. For example: `alias [name]="[script]"`
Since you are trying to make a test command that sends an output of "hi", you would enter *test* where [name] is, and *echo hi* where [script] is. Do not forget to use quotations around the script